# Local Query omits/ignores projection with "select"

Tags: breeze

Model (exposed mapping table for many-to-many relation):

```
 public class TeamUsers
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long TeamUsersId { get; set; }

    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public bool Temporary { get; set; }
}
```

Two general methods for remote and local query:

```
getAllOfTypeSelectRemote = function (manager, success, failed, resource, orderBy, predicate, select) {
            var query = EntityQuery
                .from(resource)
                .where(predicate)
                .using(manager)
                .select(select)   //<------
                .orderBy(orderBy);
            return query.execute()
                .then(success)
                .fail(failed);
        },

getAllOfTypeSelectLocally = function (manager, resource, orderBy, predicate, select) {
            var res = null;
            try {
                res = EntityQuery
                .from(resource)
                .where(predicate)
                .select(select)   //<-----
                .orderBy(orderBy)
                .using(manager)
                .executeLocally();
            } catch (e) {
                logger.error('resource: ' + resource + '<br>select: ' + select + '<br>orderBy:' + orderBy, 'Local query failed!');
            }
            return res;
        };
```

called this way:

```
var selectStr = 'User'; //<------

            var p1 = new breeze.Predicate("Team.TeamName", Qop.Equals, team);
            var p2 = breeze.Predicate("User.UserName", Qop.NotEquals, username);
            var predicate = p1.and(p2);

            //var res = dsUtils.getAllOfTypeSelectRemote(manager, success, queryFailed, 'TeamUsers', 'User.Nachname, User.Vorname', p1, select);
            var res = dsUtils.getAllOfTypeSelectLocally(manager, 'TeamUsers', 'User.Nachname, User.Vorname', p1, selectStr);
```

The remote query returns an array of User-Entities which is correct i believe. Modifying 'selectStr' to an invalid type like 'bla' throws an exception as expected.
result:

```
data.results = [{"User": {...}}, {"User": {...}}]
```

The local query just ignores the select and returns an array of TeamUser
result:

```
res=[{ Here are the fields of TeamUsers }, { Here are the fields of TeamUsers }]
```

Modifying 'selectStr' to an invalid type like 'bla' throws NO exception.
Why is select omitted, is this supposed to be like that?

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears Breeze is not applying the `select` clause to cache queries. I've filed a defect report internally. Meanwhile, can you work around it by using `Array.Map` on the filtered results?

Comment: I am using the remote version now which works. If i find the time i will try to get the local version working.

Comment: Hi, ArrayMap or ArrayFilter (from Knockout) work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v 0.74.3, this should be fixed; i.e. select clauses will now be correctly interpreted by local queries as well as remote queries.  Hope this helps.